How do I make an arc respect the coordinate system?
I'm currently trying to draw an arc which lies normal to a line. However, the command is using the page coordinate system rather than the tangent coordinate system.
Here is the code, adapted from this answer:
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        tangent/.style={
            decoration={
                markings,% switch on markings
                mark=
                at position #1
                with
                {
                    \coordinate (tangent point-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,0pt);
                    \coordinate (tangent unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (1,0pt);
                    \coordinate (tangent orthogonal unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,1);
                }
            },
            postaction=decorate
        },
        use tangent/.style={
            shift=(tangent point-#1),
            x=(tangent unit vector-#1),
            y=(tangent orthogonal unit vector-#1)
        },
        use tangent/.default=1
        ]       
        \draw [
        tangent=0.4,
        tangent=1
        ] (0,0)
        to (2,2)
        to (4,1);
        %\draw [blue, thick, use tangent] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
        \draw [orange, thick, use tangent=2] (0,0) -- (.5,0) arc [start angle=180, end angle=270, radius=1cm];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

And here is the result:

As you can see, the orange line respects the coordinate system perfectly well, but the arc doesn't. I expected the arc's initial tangent to be perpendicular to the orange line, but it isn't.
Is there something I'm missing?

Don't use 1cm (which is a length which acts in the canvas coordinate system), use 1 or whatever its radius should be to work in the xyz coordinate system (that's the one you set with x and y in the use tangent key).

I just tried Qrrbrbirlbel's suggestion, and replaced 1cm with 1, and that fixed the problem immediately.
I presume the TikZ manual says something about the additional information units carry, because the fact that cm implies a coordinate system rather than a mere distance is really counterintuitive, but I couldn't find anything on the matter.
A pointer to the right section would be most useful, if anyone wants to provide one.

Coordinate Systems would be the place to start learning about the four main coordinate systems: canvas, xyz, canvas polar and xyz polar. For the majority, you always use the implicit version, i.e. <x>, <y> and <α>:<r> where it depends on whether <x>, <y> and <r>  have units (canvas) or not (xyz). But (1, 2pt) is now a valid coordinate which combines the (1, 0) xyz vector with the (0, 2pt) vector. (And then there's actual the z dimension I'm going to leave out here.)

The implicit version uses PGFMath's result to figure out which coordinate systems to use. And the arc path operation does the same (it's basically the <r> from the polar coordinate systems). But I agree, the manual should say something about that when it introduces the arc path operation. It does so when introducing the radiu keys with the circle path operation. The next path operation, the grid makes that distinction as well.
